# Why does my timer starts at 4:00:00 ?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nstimer, nsdateformatter

My Timer is starting at 4:00:00 while I want it to start at 0:00:00.

At the beginning I was using "mm:ss" as a dateFormatter, but it was problematic because as soon as my timer gets to 60 min, it restarts from 0.

I wanted my timer to keep going over 60min so I added "hh:mm:ss", but now my timer is starting at 4:00:00 instead of 0:00:00.

```
var timer = NSTimer()
var sec = 0

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("updateTheTime"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
  }

func theTime(interval:NSTimeInterval) -> String {
    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    var date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: interval)
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "h:mm:ss"
    return dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
  }

func updateTheTime(){
    sec++
    self.timeElapsed.text = self.theTime(Double(sec))
  }
```

Comment: What's the time difference between your timezone and UTC?

Comment: @fvu: It'll bet you it's a UTC-4 tz...

Comment: The difference is 7 hours.

Comment: Try "HH:mm:ss" instead of "hh:mm:ss"

Comment: BTW, I'd discourage the use of `var timer = NSTimer()` declaration. You're creating a timer object there (which you later replace with another `NSTimer` object in `viewDidLoad`), which is probably not your intent. You probably want something like `var timer: NSTimer?` (or make it implicitly unwrapped if your app flow dictates that it won't be `nil` after it's first initialized), which declares a timer variable which is initially `nil`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remedy this by specifying the time zone for the formatter:

```
 dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0)
```

Frankly, though, I'd advise against manually counting seconds yourself, and instead save the start time and then use `NSDateComponentsFormatter` to format a nice counter:

```
var timer: NSTimer?
var startTime: NSDate!

var formatter: NSDateComponentsFormatter = {
    let _formatter = NSDateComponentsFormatter()
    _formatter.allowedUnits = .CalendarUnitHour | .CalendarUnitMinute | .CalendarUnitSecond
    _formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .Pad
    return _formatter
}()

func startTimer() {
    startTime = NSDate()
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "handleTimer:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func stopTimer() {
    timer?.invalidate()
    timer = nil
}

func handleTimer(timer: NSTimer) {
    timeElapsed.text = formatter.stringFromDate(startTime, toDate: NSDate())
}
```